# Routed feature module vs Routing feature module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I am going through angular documentation. Here 2 types of feature modules are mentioned.

**Routing Module**: One where we define the routes and components to load.(This part is understandable )

But in Routed Module the definition on https://angular.io/guide/module-types is as follows

**Routed Module**: Routed feature modules are domain feature modules whose top components are the targets of router navigation routes.All lazy-loaded modules are routed feature modules by definition.

I am unable to understand this statement. Is there an example for routed module which can be referred.

**Edit:**

I researched further and found out that routed module are lazyloaded modules whose components are only loaded once they are routed to.
I referred this example.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/lazy-loading-concept-in-angular-7/

Answer (score 0):

I researched further and found out that routed module are lazyloaded modules whose components are only loaded once they are routed to. I referred this example. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/lazy-loading-concept-in-angular-7/.

The above article explains the statement mentioned in routed module.